# Django - order many to many relation on id of intermediary model without using through

Tags: python, django

I am facing issue while sorting many to many field.

I have many to many relationship on hobbies field.
I want to keep the order user adds the hobbies. This can be done by sorting the records on intermediate model id.

Many people suggested to use through and add some field for ordering.
But this creates problem while I create records using add function of related model.

Is there any way to provide meta ordering to intermediary model so it can sort by id when I access data.

My model is as  -

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):   
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField('UserHobby')

class UserHobby(models.Model):
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta ordering can be provided if you explicitly define a through model. If not, you can still use the `order_by()` method of the QuerySet object to provide the ordering that you want as below

```
user = Users.objects.get(id=1)

user.hobbies.all().order_by('id')
```